# Collision detection algorithm for large amount of 3d static objects

Tags: algorithm, collision, mesh

Is there a faster algorithm for collision detection?
I'd like to use it find the collision pairs of model in a building.

There is a related post:[Best algorithm for efficient collision detection between objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107231/best-algorithm-for-efficient-collision-detection-between-objects).

Is there any ready-to-used library? 
BTW:The 3d object is in obj format.

Comment: Are you using some kond of engine? Which programming language?

Comment: I prefer java, and am learning jmonkey engine.

Comment: From http://wiki.jmonkeyengine.org/doku.php/jme3:advanced:collision_and_intersection
-----
Assume you have two collidables a and b and want to detect collisions between them. The collision parties can be Geometries, Nodes with Geometries attached (including the rootNode), Planes, Quads, Lines, or Rays. An important restriction is that you can only collide geometry vs bounding volumes or rays. (This means for example that a must be of Type Node or Geometry and b respectively of Type BoundingBox, BoundingSphere or Ray.) 
-----
It seems collision between two geometry is not supported.